# Can we arrange voltmeters like this?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

[image: circuit]

Can we arrange two voltmeters like this?

I have no idea about this, like how it works and if it is a correct orientation.

And for my work I only know that it is correct and it reads the potential difference (both share/divide the readings with each other as per their internal resistance).

EDIT:- Please note that the voltmeter is not ideal

Comment: Of course you *can* do this... but why do you want to? What are you trying to learn about the circuit? If you're trying to measure the voltage between terminals of a battery, you can just use one voltmeter.

Comment: @Andrew questions on such topics is in my textbook... that's why I am studying this

Comment: Fair enough. It's pretty artificial from a practical point of view but there's a legitimate problem to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Voltmeters are used to measure the potential difference across given circuit elements (e.g., resistors).  Since a voltmeter is also a circuit element, the measurement of potential difference (aka voltage drop) should not be significantly affected by putting the voltmeter in the circuit.  Accordingly, voltmeters are always placed parallel to the circuit element whose resistance you are measuring, and they have a very high resistance to ensure that they do not significantly affect the measurement when providing a parallel circuit path for current to flow.  This means that voltmeters should never be placed in a series configuration in a circuit, because their very high resistance will lead to a very low current flow in the circuit, and the resulting measurement will provide information about the resistance of the voltmeter rather than the resistance of a circuit element, which is usually useless information.

Comment: What if the voltmeter is not ideal?

Comment: NO voltmeter is ideal.  All voltmeters must have a small current flowing through them in order to measure the potential difference across a resistor.  An ideal voltmeter has an infinite resistance, meaning no current flowing through it, which also means that no voltage drop can be obtained from such a meter.

Comment: @DavidWhite You can still get a reading from an ideal voltmeter. Just take the limits $R\to\infty$ and $I\to0$ while $V$ remains constant. We do the same thing for "making" ideal dipoles. Technically ideal dipoles "don't exist" since it involves a positive and negative charge in the same location, but that's what limits are for.

Comment: While it isn't very meaningful to measure the voltage between two points on a circuit connected by a wire with low resistance (and can change the behavior of the circuit), it is meaningful to connect the two ends of the voltmeter on two terminals of a battery to measure the voltage across it.

Comment: @BioPhysicist, I assume that you would take readings with a voltmeter, plot them, and extrapolate a line to obtain the limit as current approaches zero?

Answer (score 1):

If the first voltmeter has (large, ideally infinite) resistance $R_1$ and the second voltmeter has (large, ideally infinite) resistance $R_2$ then the voltage across the first voltmeter would read
$$ \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} E$$
and the second voltmeter would read
$$ \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} E$$
Voltmeter's really measure current and are calibrated to read volts if the resistance of the meter is known $( V = I \times R)$.

The sum of the voltmeter readings would be $E$. If the voltmeters were identical each would read $E/2$.

Answer (score 0):

A voltmeter reads the voltage drop across it.

Normally, voltmeters are connected in parallel to other circuit elements.  Since all elements connected in parallel have the same voltage drop, the reading on the voltmeter is the same as the voltage drop across the other elements.

Adding a new element changes the circuit, which changes the current through and voltage drop across the other elements.  To minimize this effect, a voltmeter's resistance should be large compared to the other elements in the circuit.  This way it will draw very little current.  A voltmeter is a big resistor.

What happens when you connect two large resistors to a battery like that?  Are the voltmeters identical?  You can use Kirchhoff's laws to determine the voltage drop across and current through each.